# .NET 6 : SignOutAsync, subsequent requests with same cookie are authenticated

Tags: .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I have an app using react and .NET Core and OAuth.

On sign in, I do a

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", claimsPrincipalWithClaims, authProps)
```

When I sign out, I run

```
httpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies")
```

I get logged out of the UI, but I can still get a 200 when I replicate the request in postman - I can still get a 200 until session expires.

On subsequent requests after post logout, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still true.

Each endpoint is decorated with `[Authorize]`, but still returns a 200 post logout.

The logout endpoint returns a `Set-Cookie` header with:

`.AspNetCore.Cookies=; expites Thu, 01 Jan 1970 GMP; path=/; secure; samesite=string; httponly;`

Which kills app connectivity, but serverside - the session is still alive.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Though, you have not posted exactly how and where you are calling `httpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies")`, but I assume, you might be missing `async` and `await` in your method, that could be causing this behavior.

Can you please try below method?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Logout()
{
    // To sign out the current user and delete their cookie, call SignOutAsync:
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies", new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
}
```